# Можно ли в Angular 2 использовать Injector

Tags: javascript, angular2, typescript

Пишу обычно так

```
constructor(protected injector: Injector) {
 this.cookieService = injector.get(CookieService);
}
```

Один человек сказал что это плохо так делать но не обосновал, подскажите где почитать на эту тему.

Говорит нужно делать только так

```
constructor(protected cookieService: СookieService) {  
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Плохо ли? Не уверен.(Бывают случаи когда надо использовать **Injecter**. Пример это Angular5 и HttpInterceptor который нельзя прямо инжектить тк он выдает ошибку circular dependency) Просто второй вариант более лаконичен и более понятен. Все что вам нужно знать это то что DI(Dependency injection) сделает все за вас вам лишь остается сделать 2 вещи.

- В модуле `X` в **providers** добавить Класс который вы хотите добавить в контейнер DI. (Пример ниже)

  Добавить в конструктор класс который вы хотите получить из DI контейнера

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    //and others
  ],
  //Вот сюда добовляете классы который надо инжектить
  providers: [
    RestaurantService
  ]
})
export class XModule { }
```

Прочитать можете тут https://habrahabr.ru/post/281449/